# Setting item value from localStorage.getItem to use it in computation

Tags: oracle-apex

I've got item `P_ITEM_1`, which source is `localStorage.getItem(AA:BB)`. I need this value to sql query, that set other item value.

example:

```
`select a from dual where a = :P_ITEM_1;`
```

When i use it as computation, it's return null. But if i call $v(P_ITEM_1) in console, it's return correct value.

I've tried **DA set value**, **using JS in DA** and **Setting value with JS in section "Execute when page load"**

Is there any way to set item value from localStorage and then use it in query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done in a dynamic action. Computations happen on the server side - there is no connection with the client storage at that point.

Steps are:

Dynamic action on page load with actions:

1. Set the value (source javascript expression)
2. Refresh the report (make sure the report has items to submit set to `P1_ITEM_1`)

Comment: I had to submit item. Thanks!